# How to set dynamic position dialog jquery modal when slide body page scrolling

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need set position dialog is dynamic when user scrolling slide body page, I mean dialog always in center position when user scrolled in behind dialog. (jqueryui in asp.net)

like dialog in [this link](http://tautologistics.com/projects/jquery.modaldialog/doc/1.0.0/) (other dialog)
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

set the modal dialog's CSS position to "fixed" from "absolute".

add this class to your style.css file or whatever you use as a style file,

```
.fixed {
     position:fixed;
}
```

then in your dialog code, add this setting :

```
dialogClass: "fixed"
```

Comment: i'm can't find fixed for position in css(jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.css). you was try before? thanks.

Comment: yes, i use it, with image background. but, i was set position to fixed and remove overlay it's not happend

Comment: i call when click button. this code call dialog show from code behind                 Page.RegisterStartupScript("Message From Web", "<script> $(document).ready(function () {$( '#dialog-modal' ).dialog({modal: true, width: 750, maxWidth: 750,draggable: true,resizable: false,position:'center',zindex:1500,closeOnEscape: false,close: function() { $('#dialog-modal .dtpDateOfBirth').datepicker('hide');} });$('#dialog-modal').parent().appendTo($('form:first')); })</script>")